# Get a List of available Enums

Tags: c#

I have the enum structure as follows:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
   One=1,
   Two=2,
   Three=3
}
```

Now I want to get a list of `MyEnum`, i.e., `List<MyEnum>` that contains all the `One`, `Two` `Three`. [Again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782096/convert-listt-to-object), I am looking for a one liner that does the thing. I came out with a LINQ query but it was unsatisfactory because it was a bit too long, I think:

```
Enum.GetNames(typeof(MyEnum))
                            .Select(exEnum =>
                                (MyEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), exEnum))
                            .ToList();
```

A better suggestion?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)).Cast<MyEnum>();
```

Comment: Of course, ToList() it if you really need to make a List<MyEnum> in particular.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @mquander's code.

However, I would suggest you also *cache* the list, since it's extremely unlikely to change over the course of the execution of your program. Put it in a static readonly variable in some global location:

```
public static class MyGlobals
{
   public static readonly List<MyEnum> EnumList = 
       Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)).Cast<MyEnum>().ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not a one liner (well the implementation isn't, but the method is :P), but perhaps add something like [this](http://devlicio.us/blogs/joe_niland/archive/2006/10/10/Generic-Enum-to-List_3C00_T_3E00_-converter.aspx) to a tools/ utility class which will return a generic list:

```
public static List<T> EnumToList<T>()

{

 Type enumType = typeof(T);

 // Can't use type constraints on value types, so have to do check like this

 if (enumType.BaseType != typeof(Enum))

  throw new ArgumentException("T must be of type System.Enum");

 return new List<T>(Enum.GetValues(enumType) as IEnumerable<T>);

}
```

Comment: I would have prefer my own solution to yours.

Comment: Wouldn't it be nice if C# had a "where T : enum" generic constraint?

Comment: That's fine, but did you really need to downvote my suggestion? heh

Comment: Thanks, but I've already provided a link to that in my post Olivieri