# how to convert a genericlist to an object array -> object[]

Tags: c#, linq

I googled and fined this link, but still not working
[Convert List<T> to object[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782096/convert-listt-to-object)

I want to convert the list of int to object array. Why? because I want to add the list as object array in Combbox, it's the argument.

The problem is it adds just "one item" Object[] Array in Combobox, while "tempList" contains 4 items of type int.

I like to add the 4 items in the object[] (object array), now it adds as 1 item and just shows Object[] array in the debugger.

When I look in debugger and type :

customers    -  it shows object[1]   and when I type

customers[0] it shows object[4], so in fact 4 items are added, but how can I get these values.???

```
List<int> tempList= new CustomersRepository().GetAll().Select(a => a.Numero).ToList();
object[] customers = new object[] { tempList.Cast<object>().ToArray() };
ComboBox.Items.AddRange(customers);
```

Comment: Where do you find the method `AddRange` on a `comboBox`? I think you mean `Items.AddRange`

Comment: yes,  indeed type error. it's combobox.items.addrange(xx), just corrected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are doing is currently creating an Array of arrays. So accessing the values would be done by the following :

```
customers[0][1]
```

What I suspect you are actually looking for is the following :

```
object[] customers = tempList.Cast<object>().ToArray();
```

This will create an Array of object items called `customers`.

Answer (score 3):

```
List<int> tempList= ...;
object[] customers  = tempList.Cast<Object>().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try it this way :

```
var customers = tempList.Cast<object>().ToArray();
```

Or also with an explicit cast :

```
var customers = tempList.Select(t => (object)t).ToArray();
```

The problem occured because you are using an initializer for building your list.

This syntax :

```
var arr = new object[] { "a", "b" }
```

initialize an array with two strings.

So when you are writing

```
var arr = new object[] { tempList.Cast<object>().ToArray() }
```

you build an array of one array!

Answer (score 2):

```
object[] customers = new object[] { tempList.Cast<object>().ToArray() };
```

Here you create an `object[]` with one item: *another* `object[]` containing the items of `tempList`.

---

Just use `object[] customers = tempList.Cast<Object>().ToArray()` instead of wrapping it in *another* `object[]`.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need `ToList()` if you anyway want to process further and obtain an array later.
Something like this should be more efficient:

```
var temp = new CustomersRepository().GetAll().Select(a => a.Numero);
object[] customers = temp.Cast<object>().ToArray();
ComboBox.Items.AddRange(customers);
```

---

Had temp been a collection of reference types, you need not cast at all, but rely on array covariance. This should work:

```
var temp = new CustomersRepository().GetAll().Select(a => a.StringProperty);
object[] customers = temp.ToArray(); //no need of Cast<object>
ComboBox.Items.AddRange(customers);
```

But this doesn't work in your case since [array covariance doesnt support for value types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12454794/why-covariance-and-contravariance-do-not-support-value-type).

---

Another idea is to have an extension method `AddRange` that accepts any `IEnumerable`, not just `object[]`. Something like:

```
public static void AddRange(this IList list, IEnumerable lstObject)
{
    foreach (T t in lstObject)
        list.Add(t);
}
```

Now you can call:

```
var customers = new CustomersRepository().GetAll().Select(a => a.Numero);
ComboBox.Items.AddRange(customers);
```

---

The best of all is to add the `Customer`s as such, and set the `DisplayMember` or `ValueMember` properties to your property, like `Numero`. Since you have the entire objects in combobox you have more info with you. Something like:

```
ComboBox.DisplayMember = "Numero";
var customers = new CustomersRepository().GetAll();
ComboBox.Items.AddRange(customers); // using the above extension method
```