# Need to add Parameters to NewActionConfiguration but cant use a foreach inside the definition

Tags: c#, arrays, xml, foreach, apache-axis

Using Axis Communications VAPIX WSDL APIs - I'm setting up a `NewActionConfiguration` which takes a number of parameters that I have saved in a List but the way the API documents have the implementation I cant loop through my parameter list XML objects while defining the `newAction` object.

```
//This is how the API docs say to do it:
NewActionConfiguration newAction = new NewActionConfiguration
{
    TemplateToken = overlayToken,
    Name = "Overlay Text",
    Parameters = new ActionParameters
    {
        Parameter = new[]
        {
            new ActionParameter { Name = "text", Value = "Trigger:Active" },
            new ActionParameter { Name = "channels", Value = "1" },
            new ActionParameter { Name = "duration", Value = "15" }
         }
     }
};

//This is what I need to do:
 NewActionConfiguration newAction = new NewActionConfiguration
 {
     Name = xmlPrimaryAction["Name"].InnerText,
     TemplateToken = xmlPrimaryAction["ActionTemplate"].InnerText,
     Parameters = new[]
     {
         foreach (ActionParameter actionParameter in actionParameterList)
         {
             new ActionParameter { Name = actionParameter.Name, Value = actionParameter.Value };
          }
      }
};
```

The API will not allow me to just do a: `newAction.Parameters.Parameter.Add(actionParameter)` or the like. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Sorry. I'm a little confused. What exactly is "the API" in this context?  Are you coding within the API? Are you calling an API?

Comment: its Axis Communications VAPIX WSDL API

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. I guess what I'm asking is... how can this mysterious API determine how you write your code?

Comment: it just doesn't allow me to use a foreach inside of its bracket definition of this new object and i cant write out the parameters one-by-one because sometimes it may be more than just 3 parameters

Comment: But HOW does it now allow you? HOW does it have any say over how you create your code?

Comment: 'newAction.Parameters.Parameter' is an array data type and if i make a new[] { new ActionParameter {....}} it clears my array each time it comes around.

Comment: Can you show the NewActionConfiguration class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! Thanks for the help @Vitor you were close but learned how to cast my list as my object after i found this: [Convert List to object[]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/782104/6466389)

Here's what finally worked:

```
var actionParameterList = new List<ActionParameter>();
foreach (XmlNode xmlParameter in xmlActionParameters)
{
    ActionParameter actionParameter = new ActionParameter();
    actionParameter.Name = xmlParameter["Name"].InnerText;
    actionParameter.Value = xmlParameter["Value"].InnerText;
    actionParameterList.Add(new ActionParameter { Name = actionParameter.Name, Value = actionParameter.Value });
}
 NewActionConfiguration newAction = new NewActionConfiguration
 {
     Name = xmlPrimaryAction["Name"].InnerText,
     TemplateToken = xmlPrimaryAction["ActionTemplate"].InnerText,
     Parameters = new ActionParameters
     {
         Parameter = actionParameterList.Cast<ActionParameter>().ToArray()
     }
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

So first things, you cannot declare a foreach block inside an object instantiating scope block. What you need to do is declare a variable before, in the function scope and then attribute the Parameter property to it. Like so:

```
var actionParameters = new List<ActionParameter>();
foreach (ActionParameter actionParameter in actionParameterList)
     {
         actionParameters.Add(new ActionParameter { Name = actionParameter.Name, Value = actionParameter.Value });
      }
NewActionConfiguration newAction = new NewActionConfiguration
 {
     Name = xmlPrimaryAction["Name"].InnerText,
     TemplateToken = xmlPrimaryAction["ActionTemplate"].InnerText,
     Parameters = actionParameters.ToArray()//Use System.Linq here to convert the list into an array
};
```

Comment: i see what you're doin' i think... shoot i'm not very familiar with LINQ.

Comment: Oh it is simple, just put on the top of the file using System.Linq; and you are good to go. Did it work?

Comment: ERROR: Cannot initialize type `ActionParameters` with a collection initializer because it does not implement `System.Collections.IEnumerable`

Comment: I just read the docs, List implements the IEnumerable interface, so removing the method ToArray should work, for converting it